# Splitting a string in a list to find and replace elements in python

Tags: python, list, replace, split

I have a list of currency pairs, let's say for example it looks like this:

```
cp = ['EURUSD', 'CHFUSD', 'JPYUSD', 'CADUSD']
```

What I'm looking to do is iterate through this list, changing the USD to GBP to result in a new list that would display:

```
new_cp = ['EURGBP', 'CHFGBP', 'JPYGBP', 'CADGBP']
```

The way I assumed I would do it would be to loop through each pair, split the string into a list, remove the last 3 elements, and then append 'G', 'B', 'P' as the new last 3 elements, and finally returning this back in to a string, and adding it to the new list, 'new_cp'.

The code I began with was:

```
for pair in cp:
   split_pair = pair.split()
```

However, all this results in is getting:

```
['EURUSD']
['CHFUSD']
```

etc.

So it's just splitting the list, not splitting the string for each currency pair within the list.

I know this is relatively beginner stuff, but I am really stumped. I just don't get why this doesn't work.

If you can help with what I am doing wrong there, or even suggest a more efficient way to achieve what I'm looking to do that would be really appreciated.

Comment: How is `.split` supposed to know that you mean split into two sets of three characters? By default, it splits on any *whitespace*, of which there is none.

Comment: `.split()` without an argument, splits on whitespace, it won't magically identify you want the boundary at `'USD'`/ after 3 chars- consider instead slicing the string or using `.replace()`

Comment: your data structure looks sub-optimal too, a list of tuples or a dict, would seem more natural e.g. `[('EUR', 'USD'), ('CHF', 'USD')]` etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest using the `.replace()` method

For example:

```py
cp = ['EURUSD', 'CHFUSD', 'JPYUSD', 'CADUSD']
new_cp = []

for currency in cp:
    new_cp.append(currency.replace('USD', 'GBP'))

print(new_cp)

>> ['EURGBP', 'CHFGBP', 'JPYGBP', 'CADGBP']
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: one liner: [(currency.replace('USD', 'GBP') for currency in ['EURUSD', 'CHFUSD', 'JPYUSD', 'CADUSD']]

Answer (score 4):

You could achieve this by using `replace` in a list comprehension:

```
cp = ['EURUSD', 'CHFUSD', 'JPYUSD', 'CADUSD']
new_cp = [word.replace('USD', 'GBP') for word in cp] 
#i.e.: for word in cp, we apply the specified function to it - replace the 'USD' in that word with 'GBP' - and then append it to a new list
print(new_cp)
```

outputs: `['EURGBP', 'CHFGBP', 'JPYGBP', 'CADGBP']`

Answer (score 3):

If you know that each currency pair will contain `USD` as the last three characters, the more efficient way is to just use list indexing and append `GBP`:

```
new_cp = [i[:-3] + 'GBP' for i in cp]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution.
You can use RegEx to replace the Currency values.

```
import re

cp = ['EURUSD', 'CHFUSD', 'JPYUSD', 'CADUSD']

mycurr = 'GBP'

to_curr = re.compile("USD")

for pair in cp:
    print(to_curr.sub(mycurr, pair))
```

***Output:***

```
EURGBP
CHFGBP
JPYGBP
CADGBP
```